# Angular 6 SCSS compile error from util.js

Tags: angular, sass

I'm just starting out with Angular 6, using the Angular CLI and getting familiar with the file structure. I intend on using SCSS to create a singular global stylesheet. However, when i compile i am receiving the error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/top-bar/top-bar.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

// Copyright Joyent, Inc. and other Node contributors.
^
Invalid CSS after "...N THE SOFTWARE.": expected 1 selector or at- 
rule, was "var formatRegExp = "
in /Users/me/Documents/projects/node_modules/util/util.js 
(line 1, column 1)
```

My custom scss folder is located under `src/assets/scss`.

My top-bar component is located under `src/app/top-bar`.

I am trying to access `src/assets/scss/app.scss` in `src/app/top-bar/top-bar.component.scss` and receiving the above error.

I've tried numerous ways of importing the file `@import "~/assets/scss/app.scss";` and `@import "../assets/scss/app.scss";` to include the necessary variables but i cant be sure of what i'm doing wrong as the error seems vague and not pointed at any specific file besides a core angular utility.

If anyone can shed some light, even on the debugging process for such an error it would help immensely.

Comment: did you `npm install node-sass` ? did it go ok ?

Comment: Yes, no problems. I actually went with the SCSS option during creation of the app. Which gave me by base scss file. However i did attempt to install `node-sass` as well to see if that was the case.

Comment: `//` is invalid in CSS  but its ok in `SCSS` your'e failing on that. this makes me think your SCSS is not compiling

Comment: I am aware. My problem is that with a typical SCSS error i would expect a point in the direction of the source. I've even tried a simple SCSS file with 2 rules and still get this fairly vague error.

Comment: can you add your `angular.json` file content

Comment: Are you looking specifically for the schematics ? I've declared the `"styleext":scss"` as well as directing my `styles:["src/app.scss"]`. Do you need to see anything specifically?

Comment: It'd be good to see the complete angular.json to double check the json nesting and such. Maybe the props need to be set at a different level?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. The root cause is a bug in the SCSS file loader/resolver used by webpack (used by the @angular/cli) that loads JS files in addition to SCSS files.

The bug is that JS files take precedence over SCSS files. The GitHub issue is here:

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/556

The bad news is that the issue has been open for 8 months, and pull requests to fix it haven't been accepted.

The good news is that you can work around the problem by using SCSS file names that don't match JS filenames in `node_modules` subdirectories.

For example, I had a SCSS file named `_util.scss`, and so my error was:

```
  Invalid CSS after "...N THE SOFTWARE.": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var formatRegExp = "      
     in C:\src\project\node_modules\util\util.js (line 1, column 1)
```

My fix was to rename my SCSS file to `_sass-util.scss`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @crimbo the problem is in https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/556 , but I cannot rename files, because I use third party library ( **Foundation 6** ).

I have downgraded to **sass-loader@6.0.7**

```
npm install --save-dev sass-loader@6.0.7
```

and it works for me for **Angular 7.1.4** which used originally **sass-loader@7.1.0**

As per release notes https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases/tag/v7.0.0 the breaking changes are:

- Drop official node 4 support
- This slightly changes the resolving algorithm. Should not break in normal usage, but might break in complex configurations.
- The sass-loader throws an error at runtime now and refuses to compile if the peer dependency is wrong. This could break applications where npm's peer dependency warning was just ignored.

which are not problem for my case

Comment: Good addition. Might want to change it to `npm install --save-dev ...` just to avoid adding a run-time dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for Angular7+ (unable to revert sass-loader version) & Foundation6+ & SASS combination:

Do not `@import util/util` from foundation in your .scss files but separated packages combination (breakpoint, color, direction, flex, math, mixins, selector, typography, unit, value), based on what you need or trick it with `./util/util`. Also `foundation.scss` and `settings.scss` imports util inside them and so this files should be avoided or patched locally until sass-loader fix.